# How to distinguish between bind() in sys/sockets.h and std::bind?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm using g++ 4.6.0 to compile some C++ code that successfully compiled in earlier versions.

```
if ( bind(iControl, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)) == -1)
  throw runtime_error ("bind");
```

where iControl is a socket, and sa is a `struct sockaddr_in`.

However, in g++ 4.6 I get the following error:

```
comms.cpp:93:66: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘std::bind(_Functor&&, _ArgTypes&& ...) [with _Functor = int&, _ArgTypes = {sockaddr*, long unsigned int}, typename std::_Bind_helper<_Functor, _ArgTypes>::type = std::_Bind<int(sockaddr*, long unsigned int)>]((* &((sockaddr*)(& sa))), (* &16ul)) == -0x00000000000000001’
```

comms.cpp:93:66: note: candidates are:

followed by about a page and a half of possible candidates.

It appears to be mixing up the bind function in `sys/sockets.h` with std::bind in `functional` . How do I disambiguate the two without rewriting my whole source file to remove `using namespace std`?

Comment: Wanna know why `using namespace std;` isn't such a great idea?:-)

Comment: Similar issues can rise when you use OpenCV.

Comment: @BoPersson I may have discovered why :P But this code predates me, in my defense.

Comment: got the same problem today. Even widely used library hiphop has `using namespace std;` in the beginning of source files and the code breaks in g++4.6

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Qualify it to be global: `::bind(...)` (and make sure you have all the right headers included).

EDIT: (I got the idea from @Bo Persson's comment)
Another solid option is to change `using namespace std;` to several `using <thing>` like:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
// etc.
```

This lets your old code compile and doesn't bring `std::bind` into the global namespace.

Comment: I'm lost here, having had this problem this morning.  Where is this _Bind_helper coming from and why is "using namespace std" a bad thing in this context?